# Setting caret position in contenteditable in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, contenteditable, caret

In my html I have a `contenteditable` field with an empty `<strong>` tag inside. When a user clicks into this field, I want their typing to occur *inside* that empty tag. When we implemented this behavior before, Chrome used to behave appropriately, and placed your caret inside the element, and allowed you to type w/ your text `<strong>`'ed, now, however, Chrome places your caret before the tag, and it very much ruins the formatting.

At the time, Firefox did not put your caret inside the empty tag, so we implemented this code to get Firefox to function properly:

```
$(document).on "mousedown click", ".data_inline", (e) ->
  $child = $(this).children().first()


  if $child.length == 1 && $.trim($child.html()) == ''
    # Feature detection
    if window.getSelection && document.createRange
      range = document.createRange()
      range.selectNodeContents($child[0])
      sel = window.getSelection()
      sel.removeAllRanges()
      sel.addRange(range)
```

This worked great, and made both Firefox and Chrome browsers treat that field correctly. *Now*, for whatever reason, Firefox is still working, but Chrome is not. Chrome puts your caret before the element, and your typing occurs outside of the `<strong>` (or sometimes `<u>`).

I've made an example of this awkward behavior here: 
https://codepen.io/nzifnab/pen/oGJLNW

As you can see, if you click into the first field in Chrome and start typing, it leaves a big chunk of whitespace at the end (due to the css rule of that field being `:empty`), because your caret is *before* the empty tag that it should be inside of. The `sel.addRange(range)` appears to be doing nothing... And I'm not sure what I can do to fix it. The second field, if you click into it, correctly highlights the *contents* of the `<strong>`, and typing will do as expected, give you bolded text.

Both fields work correctly in Firefox *and* in Edge.

Comment: to fix it you could use `&nbsp;` instead of space, tested in chrome and seems to work fine.

Comment: Instead of what space? Using a `&nbsp;` causes the field to collapse because of the CSS rules, which is undesirable, but we *do* want it to collapse if a user actually starts typing in the field.